# Sorted Dictionary with number of occurrence of each letter

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, dictionary, data-structures

Imagine we have an array of Strings like {"hello","world","helloo"} and we need to print this:

hello = l:2, h:1, e:1, o:1

helloo = l:2, o:2, h:1, e:1

world = w:1, o:1, r:1, l:1, d:1

As you can see, we need a lexicographically sorted dictionary(hello, helloo, world) and each word shows a sorted number of occurrence of each character in the word.

What is the best data structure in Java to store the result here?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have to maintain it in sorted order? Can you just use a regular dictionary, and then just sort it when you need to print?

Comment: how come it shows the sorted occurence , hello = l:2, h:1, e:1, o:1,  how come l is before h

Comment: `TreeMap<String, LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>>` with the inner map created from an entry set sorted by `Entry::getValue`.

Comment: @JimMischel It was an interview question, there is no particular reason

Comment: @IshaAgarwal it doesn't matter which one come first for equal numbers

Answer (score 0):

I would use `TreeMap<String, TreeMap<Character, Integer>>`, where the outer map has a natural order, the inner map is sorted according to the character occurrence count and first position (this matches your example output).

The code then looks like this:

```
  private static TreeMap<String, Map<Character, Integer>> tokenize(String[] words) {
    TreeMap<String, Map<Character, Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for (String word : words) {
      Map<Character, Integer> counterMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
      Map<Character, Integer> positionMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
        char ch = word.charAt(i);
        int current = counterMap.getOrDefault(ch, 0);
        counterMap.put(ch, current + 1);
        positionMap.putIfAbsent(ch, i);
      }

      TreeMap<Character, Integer> sortedCounterMap = new TreeMap<>((ch1, ch2) -> {
        int counterCmp = counterMap.get(ch2) - counterMap.get(ch1);
        if (counterCmp != 0) return counterCmp;
        return positionMap.get(ch1) - positionMap.get(ch2);
      });
      sortedCounterMap.putAll(counterMap);

      map.put(word, sortedCounterMap);
    }
    return map;
  }
```

If the order of characters with same occurrence count is unspecified, the inner sort can be slightly simplified, though the idea is the same:

```
private static TreeMap<String, Map<Character, Integer>> tokenize(String[] words) {
    TreeMap<String, Map<Character, Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for (String word : words) {
      Map<Character, Integer> counterMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
        char ch = word.charAt(i);
        int current = counterMap.getOrDefault(ch, 0);
        counterMap.put(ch, current + 1);
      }

      TreeMap<Character, Integer> sortedCounterMap = new TreeMap<>((ch1, ch2) -> {
        int counterCmp = counterMap.get(ch2) - counterMap.get(ch1);
        if (counterCmp != 0) return counterCmp;
        return ch1 - ch2;
      });
      sortedCounterMap.putAll(counterMap);

      map.put(word, sortedCounterMap);
    }
    return map;
  }
```